# Keras predict_proba predicts the same probabilities for each input (LSTM)

Tags: text, keras, lstm, text-classification, predict

My Keras sequential model produces nearly the same predictions for all inputs, when I use `predict_proba`.

It seems like the model learns nothing, bescause the loss stays nearly the same during training and the predicted probabilites roughly match the class Distribution of my Labels.

Output:

```
[[ 0.12883131  0.44906539  0.42210329]
 [ 0.12883131  0.44906539  0.42210332]
 [ 0.12883131  0.44906539  0.42210329]
 ..., 
 [ 0.12883131  0.44906539  0.42210329]
 [ 0.12883131  0.44906539  0.42210332]
 [ 0.12883131  0.44906539  0.42210332]]
```

I try to solve a document classification task and my Input is a sequence of integers, which represents word indizes received from short texts.
It's a Multi class Problem with 3 classes (as you can see)

anything wrong in general with my model params?

model:

```
embedding_size = 200
model_cat_cross = Sequential()
# Input Layer
model_cat_cross.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=32))
# LSTM Layer
model_cat_cross.add(LSTM(units=embedding_size, 
                         dropout= 0.2,
                         recurrent_dropout= 0.2))
# Output Layer
model_cat_cross.add(Dense(units=labels.shape[1], 
                          activation='softmax'))
# Modellparameter
model_cat_cross.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                        optimizer='adam', 
                        metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
print(model_cat_cross.summary())
# Training des Modells und Cross Validierung
model_cat_cross.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                    class_weight={0:3,1:1,2:1}, 
                    validation_split=0.1,
                    epochs=2, 
                    batch_size=32,
                    shuffle=1)
# save model to single file
#model.save('lstm_model_v1.h5')
```

Comment: Training a model for just two epochs makes no sense

Comment: I know, but shouldn't I see at least some minor changes in the loss function? trained it over night with 20 epochs:, no changes. could it be an Input Problem? when using pretrained cbow wordembeddings as Input, I got arround 90 acc with the first epoch, going up to ~95 in the 10th.

'Train on 73200 samples, validate on 18300 samples
Epoch 1/12
20ms/step - loss: 0.9903 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4393 - val_loss: 0.9900 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.4440
….12/12
 categorical_accuracy: 0.4416 - val_loss: 0.9892 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.4440

Comment: You see some minor changes, maybe the model is just too simple for the data you have, and you need a deeper one. In any case this is not a programming question, you always have to tune your model to fit your data.